# CLion failing to detect C/C++ compiler ABI info

Tags: cmake, clion

I have a custom toolchain for building projects. And by custom toolchain, I mean a derivative of the Clang C compiler, C++ compiler, and linker.

The project(s) build just fine, but I'm unable to use the Intellij features of CLion, because it can't build a tags database (or whatever it does under the hood) due to not being able to recognize the custom toolchain.

Thus, hitting `Tools` -> `CMake` -> `Reset Cache and Reload Project` spits out:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/<path-to-custom-toolchain>/Toolchain.cmake -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/<project-directory>/src
-- Setting up Toolchain 1.0 at /Users/<tools>/build
-- Setting up Toolchain 1.0 at /Users/<tools>/build
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 7.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 7.0.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - failed
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - failed
-- Configuring done
```

---

Screenshot of the preference options for the project (It's a link because I don't have the rep required to post images yet):

[Project Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgL8p.png)

---

So my question is, how should I go about solving this problem? Or does this problem exceed the limitations of CLion? Or do I have an incomplete understanding of the problem?

Comment: Are you also using CMake for your proper build which works? What is the command you're building your project with?

Comment: I just added a screenshot of what the Project Preference settings are. And yes, I'm using CMake for the proper build which does work.

Comment: @goldwin-es Any ideas?

Comment: If you run the same command from the terminal outside CLion (`/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/<path-to-custom-toolchain>/Toolchain.cmake -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/<project-directory>/src`) - does it work? Could you please also share the proper build command you are using?

Comment: I just added two additional screenshots to try and give you a better picture of what's going on. The first screenshot is that of just building the project; CLion seems to read the CMake files just fine, thus building the project just fine. The second screenshot is that of issuing said command in the terminal (the output is the same outside of the CLion terminal).